# The pronoun before the antecedent

Tags: grammar, pronouns

```
Joe says it helps, as the cost of the drug falls to 10$.
```

Is this correct usage in a headline of a newspaper article?

I know in some cases, it's fine for the pronoun to come before the antecedent, but this sentence just feels very strange to me.

Comment: **It's** annoying that I can't vote to migrate this question to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), because the OP has slapped a minimal bounty on **it.**

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm two non-cataphoric *it*s isn't really germane to the Q ...

Comment: @Araucaria: You have me at a loss. In what way is my first **it** any different to OP's?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah. Well, according to most linguists, your first *it* is a meaningless dummy *it* used for an extraposition. I.e. the sentence is a version of *["that I can't vote to migrate this question to English Language Learners, because the OP has slapped a minimal bounty on it] is annoying"*. The OP's allegedly is a cataphoric pronoun (which seems reasonable). If you strongly feel that yours is a cataphoric pronoun, then that's definitely worth a question (I might agree with you ... maybe).

Comment: @Araucaria: I think the distinction between dummy-it and cataphoric forward reference is obvious (and meaningful) in, say, *It's raining* as compared to [*It bit me, your dog. Someone should put it down.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+bit+me+your+dog%22). But when "it" simply refers to some (possibly later-stated, possibly contextually implicit) clause / condition / action / etc. I'm not convinced ***it's*** worth making the distinction. What exactly, for example, does my last ***it*** there refer to?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your first *it* is definitely considered a dummy *it* by most linguists. I don't know about your last it, but it looks like a dummy too, imo.

Comment: @Araucaria:: So, should we classify your ***it** looks like a dummy too* as a "dummy"? I think if asked, most people would have no hesitation in saying it's a pronoun representing the previously-mentioned ***your last*** What I'm getting at is that *somewhere* in this general area there are contexts where it's easy to identify what ***it*** represents, and other contexts (such as *It seems to me we're going nowhere with this one*) where it's effectively impossible. And there's a lot of room for uncertainty between those two extremes, where arguably the distinction becomes almost pointless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the pronoun "it" comes before the antecedent, it is known as a [Postcedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(grammar)#Postcedents).

Wikipedia lists common examples of this

> - When it is ready, I'll have a cup of coffee. - *Noun as postcedent*
> - In her bed, my friend spends the entire morning. - *Noun phrase as    postcedent*
> - It bothered me that she did not call. - *Clause as    postcedent, example of it-extraposition*
> - Two violinists were there, at the party. - *Prepositional phrase as postcedent*
> - Sam tries to work then, when it is raining. - *Clause as postcedent*

Now, we can see from these examples that is is mostly clunky but sometimes very natural (3rd example).

So yes, it's technically fine, but very clunky. Part of the issue is that "it" is very ambiguous and makes no sense to separate it from what "it" is referring to while also not saying what exactly needs helping. It makes the 2nd clause seem like an afterthought, which is fine in speech and dialogue because that is how humans often function.

A better way to write it would be

```
Joe says the cost of the drug falling to 10$ helps.
```

However, the paper wanted to give the feeling that the drug is currently falling while also implying that Joe is saying something in reaction to the drug price falling. The other way to write it isn't much better.

```
As the cost of the drug falls to $10, Joe says it helps.
```

The biggest issue is their need to force Joe and the action of the price falling into the same sentence. You can mess with the tense of the sentence and switch around "as" to "when" or "while" but it still comes out clunky.

It's just a product of trying to make a sentence accomplish too much.

Comment: Thank you. All I am trying to figure out is whether it's technically correct or not.

Comment: @user93353 technically yes, but I'd avoid using it that way since, as you can tell, it sounds weird

Answer (score 0):

Postcedents are not used as commonly. [This article](https://www.deepdyve.com/lp/elsevier/click-bait-forward-reference-as-lure-in-online-news-headlines-29oVWmFt0f) talks about how forward references (including postcedents / cataphora) are used in headlines to grab the attention of readers.

Comment: A link is not sufficient. Please summarise the main points of the article. Stack Exchange questions and answers need to stand on their own.

Answer (score 0):

There is kind of redundancy in the second part that makes the headline not flow too well. This would be better:

Drug cost falls to 10$; Joe says it helps

Comment: what about a semicolon instead?